# JavaScript реализовать алгоритм Кируса - Бека

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Ребятушки помогите пожалуйста с помощью языка JavaScript реализовать алгоритм Кируса-Бека.

```js
var context = document.getElementById("MyCanvas").getContext("2d");
var coordsX = [],
  coordsY = [];
var cordX = [],
  cordY = [];
var n = -1; // счётчик нарисованных точек
var coord = true; // переменная flag которая либо разрешат рисовать либо запрещает при false;
var x = -1;

function pseudoScalar(a1, b1, a2, b2) {
  return a1 * b2 - a2 * b1;
}


function checkPrime() {
  for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    for (var j = i + 2; j < n; j++) {
      if (pseudoScalar(coordsY[j] - coordsY[i], coordsX[i] - coordsX[j],
          coordsY[j] - coordsY[j + 1], coordsX[j + 1] - coordsX[j]) *
        pseudoScalar(coordsY[j] - coordsY[i + 1], coordsX[i + 1] - coordsX[j],
          coordsY[j] - coordsY[j + 1], coordsX[j + 1] - coordsX[j]) < 0 &&
        pseudoScalar(coordsY[i] - coordsY[j], coordsX[j] - coordsX[i],
          coordsY[i] - coordsY[i + 1], coordsX[i + 1] - coordsX[i]) *
        pseudoScalar(coordsY[i] - coordsY[j + 1], coordsX[j + 1] - coordsX[i],
          coordsY[i] - coordsY[i + 1], coordsX[i + 1] - coordsX[i]) < 0)
        return false;
    }

  return true;
}

function getCoords(event) //координаты
{
  if (coord == true) {
    n += 1;
    coordsX[n] = event.clientX - 40;
    coordsY[n] = event.clientY - 30;
    drawCircle(coordsX[n], coordsY[n], 4, "black");
    if (n > 0) {
      drawLine(coordsX[n - 1], coordsY[n - 1], coordsX[n], coordsY[n]);
    }
  }
}


function drawCircle(x, y, radius, color) // рисует точки, для построения многоугольника
{
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  context.strokeStyle = color;
  context.closePath();
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fill();
  context.stroke();
}

function drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) //соединение точек
{
  context.strokeStyle = "black";
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(x1, y1);
  context.lineTo(x2, y2);
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.stroke();

}

function graph() //соединяет первую и последнюю точк линией и заканчивает рисунок
{
  drawLine(coordsX[0], coordsY[0], coordsX[n], coordsY[n]);
  coord = false;
  if (!checkPrime()) {
    alert("Многоугольник не является простым");
    del();
  }
}

function del() // очищает прямоугольник
{
  context.clearRect(0, 0, 750, 570);
  n = -1;
  coordsX = [];
  coordsY = [];
  coord = true;
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
}

#Canvas {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  width: 1320px;
  height: 640px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left top, blue, pink);
}

.c1 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
  width: 750px;
  height: 570px;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
}

.c2 {}

.list {
  width: 500px;
  height: 570px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
}

input {
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

h4 {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  padding: 20px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru-en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Algoritm Cyrus — Beck</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="Canvas">
    <canvas id="MyCanvas" class="c1" width="750" height="570" onclick="getCoords(event)"></canvas>
    <div class="c2">
      <input type="button" name="but1" value="Закончить фигуру" title="Закончить рисование фигуры  для отсечения линий" onclick="graph()">
      <input type="button" name="but2" value="Очистить холст" onclick="del()">
    </div>
    <div class="list">
      <h4>Algoritm Cyrus-Beck</h4>
      <p> p(t)=p1+t(p1-p0),t in [0,1]<br> где p0, p1 — координаты начала и конца отрезка соответственно,<br> t — параметр.<br> Каждый отсекаемый отрезок содержит координаты начала и конца, а также два параметра tA и tB, соответствующие началу и концу отрезка.<br>        Для каждого отсекаемого отрезка P выполняются следующие действия:<br> Рёбра отсекающего многоугольника обходятся против часовой стрелки. Для каждого ребра E вычисляется параметр tE, описывающий пересечение E с прямой, на которой лежит отрезок
        P. Вычисляется скалярное произведение вектора E и внешней нормали N, в зависимости от знака которого возникает одна из следующих ситуаций:<br> E · N
        < 0 — отрезок P направлен с внутренней на внешнюю сторону ребра E. В этом случае параметр tA заменяется на tE, если tE> tA.<br> E · N > 0 — отрезок P направлен с внешней на внутреннюю сторону ребра E. В этом случае параметр tB заменяется на tE, если tE
          < tB.<br>
            E · N = 0 — отрезок P параллелен ребру E. Отрезок P отбрасывается как невидимый, если находится по правую сторону от E. Если tA
            <=t B, то заданная параметрами tA и tB часть отрезка P видима. В противном случае отрезок P полностью невидим.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

вот ссылка на материал сижу уже месяц над этим алгоритмом 
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0